# Draw a black line at the bottom of an image, PHP

Tags: php, image

I wrote this code that was supposed to draw a black line of 1px at the bottom of an image, but it isn't working as expected and it generates a totally black image:

```
    $img = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");    
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 25);
    imagecopy($dest, $img, 0, 0, $px + $position[$pos][0], $py + $position[$pos][1] , 50, 25);
    $w = imagesx($dest);
    $h = imagesy($dest);
    $out = ImageCreateTrueColor(imagesx($dest),imagesy($dest)) or die('Problem In Creating image');

    for( $x=0; $x<$w; $x++) {
        imagesetpixel($out, $x, $h, imagecolorallocate($out, 0, 0, 0));
    }
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Where are you setting the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing your line on the `$out` image, which has nothing in it.

1. You load up `$img` (the original).
2. you create `$dest`
3. you resize `$img` into `$dest`
4. you create `$out`
5. you draw the line on `$out`.

`$out` never gets a copy of either the original or resized image, so it stays at the default all-black. You then draw a black line on a black image... ending up with a black image.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$y` isn't set, I think it's just a typo, you have set `$h`, and used `$y` instead.

Comment: Thanks! But that didn't solve the error, I've noticed it few minutes ago and even if I change it the image results totally black.

P.S. $y was aleready set however so the typo didn't play a big role :)

Comment: have you tried: `imageline ( resource $image , int $x1 , int $y1 , int $x2 , int $y2 , int $color )` (seems simpler)?  Also, can you confirm the picture outputs correctly before your loop?